# Storing a char pointer into a container

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

i'm trying to store a `char*` that getting updated regularly.

i need to store the data it points to to a container in c++

i tried to use `char*` **vector** but all the elements points to the last updated `char*`.

Here's my code :

```
std::vector<const char*>Packets;
char* Packet;
void __declspec (naked) RecvCaller()
{
    __asm mov ecx, [ebp + 0x08]
    __asm mov Packet, ecx
    Packets.push_back(Packet);
    __asm jmp dwJmpBack
}
```

How could i achieve this?

Comment: You likely want `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: i want to store ```Bytes``` which may contain integers also its a ```Packet```

Comment: Yes, you have a variable named `Packet`, of type `char*`. Presumably, it points to a sequence of `char`s. `std::string` is capable of storing a sequence of `char`s. You seem to ascribe some magical properties to the word "Packet": you say "it's a Packet" as if this is self-explanatory. Yet the meaning of the program would not change if you renamed the variable `foobar`

Comment: Do you want to store the pointer in the vector or do you want to store the data the pointer points to in the vector?

Comment: @David Schwartz Ye i want to store the data the pointer points to so it does not change when the pointer points to something else

Comment: @DevilSoul Then you don't actually want to store a char pointer in a container. You want to store some characters in a container.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you want to store the pointer to Packet, rather you want to store the Packet itself.

So, you need to construct a vector of packets, create a new vector element and copy the data that is being pointed to into the vector element.

So, suppose you have a class cPacket, with a constructor that takes a char pointer, then you can write

```
class cPacket {
public:
cPacket( char* p )
{
// code to copy the data into attributes
...
}
};


std:vector< cPacket > vPacket;

...

vPacket.push_back( cPacket( Packet ) );
```

Alternatively, if the rest of your code expects a vector of pointers

```
std::vector< cPacket* > vpPacket;

...

vpPacket.push_back( new cPacket( Packet ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can push a char* into a vector.  Perhaps you are changing the value of Packet in other code?  Here is a simple example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   char * ptr;

   char a[] = "first";
   char b[] = "second";
   char c[] = "third";


   std::vector<char const *> v;
   ptr = a;
   v.push_back(ptr);
   ptr = b;
   v.push_back(ptr);
   ptr = c;
   v.push_back(ptr);
   for(auto const & element:v)
   {
    std::cout << element << std::endl;
   }
}
```

If subsequent code changes a, b or c then of course the stored char* will reflect the change.

As @ravenspoint noted, perhaps you want to make a full copy of the Packet and store that in the vector instead of a pointer.